# Count a digit integer separated by a comma

Tags: vb.net

[![enter image description here][1]][1]This is a code that displays my characters, separated by space. How can I make the code separate it with ","

so if your line is 25,16,300 the result should be 3.

```
TxtMReadOnly.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)

TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
```

everything I tried does not work in the screenshot below. but take the number, if it's 55, for example, be taken as 1, if possible.

First: not worked: only works on the first line, not on all the textbox lines.

```
TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Split(",").Count()
```

Second: does not display the values correctly.

```
TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not x = ",").Count()
```

I Edited the post:

```
  For j = 0 To TxtCheckList.Text - 1
            Dim intersectionList As New List(Of String)()
            For i As Integer = 1 To TxtCheckDraws.Text
                Dim firstBoxList = TxtBoxIntDraws.Lines(i).Split(",")
                Dim secondBoxList = TxtNumberListScan.Lines(j + 1).Split(" ")
                intersectionList.Add(String.Join(",", secondBoxList.Intersect(firstBoxList)))
            Next
            TxtMReadOnly.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, intersectionList)
            TxtNumberListCount.Text &= Environment.NewLine & TxtMReadOnly.Text.Where(Function(x) Not Char.IsWhiteSpace(x)).Count()
            Try
```

Comment: Please make it clear, do you need the code to count all non "," characters? so if your line is `25,16,300` the result should be 3?

Comment: Yes. Sure. Exactly that's want.

Comment: Using `Not` in the second code is not correct, instead use `x <> ","` but the result will be the count of all digits characters not the count of numbers, so `.Split(",").Count` should works fine.

Comment: I don't understand. can you give me exactly what I have to replace? let me just count the characters, but I do not want to count my comma. until I find something better ...

Comment: `.Text.Split(",").Count` should work with you if everything else is ok, please update your question to post a sample of the input text (lines of numbers) and the block of code which used to get numbers count of each line, so that's help to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I edited the post.